# Internal Server Error Slim and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

First I need to say ya sorry for my bad english
I hope u can help me strangers.
I have created a domian in my linux Debian 8.
look it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin admin@admin.com  
DocumentRoot "/var/www/saci"
ServerName saci.com
ServerAlias www.saci.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


<Directory "/var/www/saci">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using slim and I've created a folder named 'app' on the folder 'saci' with a file start.php that got this:

```
<?php

use Slim\App;

session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));

require INC_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App();

$app->get('/test', function() {
echo "this is a test.";
});

?>
```

Now on my folder saci I've created a folder named Public with one index.php and one .htaccess.
so now look my roots

Var > www > saci > public

index.php <------------------index daaa

.htaccess <------------------.htaccess

var > www > saci > app

start.php <----------------start

so now my problem is here 
I've got an index.php with this

```
<?php
require '../app/start.php';
$app->run();
```

and a .htaccess with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

but when I go to my host www.saci.com I can see my index of/
with all my proyects folders But I cannot see the folder public, and if I go to www.saci.com/public

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was      unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@admin.com to  inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.saci.com Port 80

I rly DON'T HAVE IDEA of what is going wrong I need rly rly help

starting now

> Thanks Steangers U rock never forget smile

Greetings from Venezuela

Comment: `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` should have some helpful information about the server error. Can you post what it says?

Comment: Sorry I felt sleep last night  programing lol
but the error.log say

                                                                                                                                [Thu Apr 21 21:59:23.092394 2016] [core:alert] [pid 4397] [client 127.0.0.1:38378] /var/www/saci/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: That means that mod_rewrite is not installed or active, so you will not be able to do any URL rewriting without it.  On Debian, create a symlink from `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load` to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load`